# MsgBox with autoit

Tags: autoit

I have this :

```
    Global $GUIAction = GUICreate("Selectionnez une Action", 345, 256, 1030, 0, -1, $WS_EX_TOPMOST)
    Global $actionList = GUICtrlCreateList("", 104, 8, 137, 188, -1, BitAND($GUI_SS_DEFAULT_LIST, $LBS_SORT))
    GUICtrlSetData(-1, "HAUT|BAS|GAUCHE|DROITE|POS PERSO|POS MAP|ZAAP|HAVRE-SAC|FLOOD|PAUSE|ECRIRE|COMBAT|COMMENTAIRE|END")

    $btnSelectActionOK = GUICtrlCreateButton("&OK", 88, 225, 75, 25)
    $btnSelectActionCancel = GUICtrlCreateButton("&Cancel", 184, 225, 75, 25)
    GUISetState(@SW_SHOW)

                        GUIDelete($GUIListeConfigs)
MsgBox(64, "", GUICtrlRead($btnSelectActionOK))
```

How to check if OK or Cancel is pressed ?

THX

Answer (score 1):

Here are two easy examples for you:

```
#include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>

Global $timeout = 3

example_1()
example_2()

Func example_1()
    Local $returnValue = MsgBox($MB_YESNO, "Example", "Press a button :-)")

    If $returnValue = $IDYES Then
        MsgBox($MB_OK, "OK", "You pressed Yes!", $timeout)
    Else
        MsgBox($MB_OK, "Ok", "You pressed No!", $timeout)
    EndIf
EndFunc   ;==>example_1

Func example_2()

    Switch MsgBox($MB_YESNOCANCEL, "Example", "Press a button :-)")
        Case $IDYES
            MsgBox($MB_OK, "OK", "You pressed Yes!", $timeout)
        Case $IDNO
            MsgBox($MB_OK, "OK", "You pressed No!", $timeout)
        Case $IDCANCEL
            MsgBox($MB_OK, "Cancel", "You pressed Cancal!", $timeout)
    EndSwitch
EndFunc   ;==>example_2
```

An example for a GUI-Button (from the help file)

```
#include <GUIConstantsEx.au3>
#include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>

Example()

; -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Example - Press the button to see the value of the radio boxes
; The script also detects state changes (closed/minimized/timeouts, etc).
Func Example()
    Opt("GUICoordMode", 1)

    GUICreate("Radio Box Demo", 400, 280)

    ; Create the controls
    Local $idButton_1 = GUICtrlCreateButton("B&utton 1", 30, 20, 120, 40)
    GUICtrlCreateGroup("Group 1", 30, 90, 165, 160)
    GUIStartGroup()
    Local $idRadio_1 = GUICtrlCreateRadio("Radio &0", 50, 120, 70, 20)
    GUICtrlCreateRadio("Radio &1", 50, 150, 60, 20)
    Local $idRadio_3 = GUICtrlCreateRadio("Radio &2", 50, 180, 60, 20)

    ; Init our vars that we will use to keep track of GUI events
    Local $iRadioVal1 = 0 ; We will assume 0 = first radio button selected, 2 = last button

    ; Show the GUI
    GUISetState(@SW_SHOW)

    Local $idMsg = 0
    ; In this message loop we use variables to keep track of changes to the radios, another
    ; way would be to use GUICtrlRead() at the end to read in the state of each control
    While 1
        $idMsg = GUIGetMsg()
        Select
            Case $idMsg = $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE
                MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "", "Dialog was closed")
                ExitLoop
            Case $idMsg = $GUI_EVENT_MINIMIZE
                MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "", "Dialog minimized", 2)
            Case $idMsg = $GUI_EVENT_MAXIMIZE
                MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "", "Dialog restored", 2)

            Case $idMsg = $idButton_1
                MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "", "Default button clicked:" & @CRLF & "Radio " & $iRadioVal1)

            Case $idMsg >= $idRadio_1 And $idMsg <= $idRadio_3
                $iRadioVal1 = $idMsg - $idRadio_1

        EndSelect
    WEnd

    GUIDelete()
EndFunc   ;==>Example
```